# Swift typealias and casting odd behavior

Tags: ios, swift

I have such typealias

```
typealias FormField = UIView & Validatable
```

I consider it as FormField is UIView type that conforms additonally to Validatable 
But when I do type casting objects pulled from array to this FormField type or check with is operator it returns is castable (returns true) for object that is not UIView

> po formFields[fieldId] is FormField
>       true

where

```
var formFields : [FieldId: ValidatableField] { get set }
```

and here is

```
typealias ValidatableField = AnyObject & Validatable
```

So in array I have any objects conforming to Validatable and now I want to cast to UIView conforming to Validatable and this casting works even for object types that are not UIView!

At the and I need to make such code:

```
func formField(with id: FieldId) -> FormField? {
        let field = formFields[id]
        if field is UIView {
            return field as? FormField
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Instead of simple oneliner:

```
func formField(with id: FieldId) -> FormField? {
         return formFields[id] as? FormField
 }
```

Comment: All classes conform to `AnyObject` so it will work for all classes. Did you get the same result for `struct` or even able to compile?

Comment: This is definitely a compiler bug. I've opened a defect: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11565

Comment: Note that while this is definitely a compiler bug, I would also encourage you to rethink your design here. When you find yourself `as?` casting protocols back to their underlying types, you're often thinking about protocols incorrectly. It's suspicious that `formFields` doesn't actually contain `FormField`. `as?` should generally be a last resort, and almost always should be used when data is entering the system from a system with weaker types (such as ObjC). If you're doing it as part of pure Swift data structures, it suggests a design issue.

Comment: @RobNapier your bug code doesn't work. Because CP is declared twice

Comment: @Vyacheslav That was an injected problem when I edited the bug to make some things more clear. It's not the problem. Thanks; fixed.

Comment: @RobNapier btw, `SubCP` is not actually used inside your example:) and there is no explanation of this class:)

Comment: I know; it was just there to show that some C's are P, but not all of them. Commented.

Comment: @RobNapier nonetheless nice example:)

Comment: yes naming of formFields dictionary is a little peculiar in this situation as this changed while protocols evolved it will be better named